# editing header file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sorry to bother u guys with such fool question...im very sorry..i just need to use rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui to adjust it...im such a fool to ask first before investigate...it has nothing to do with roboearth...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33959/editing-header-file/) by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This depends on how you've installed the roboearth package. If it's been installed as a binary (via, say, `apt-get install ...`), then editing it won't do anything.

To build it from source, you'll need to download the source using rosinstall (see the docs for rosinstall, and the "source" line in the list at the very top of the roboearth wiki page). Then, build it using `rosmake`. Because you're building it from source, any changes you make will take effect as soon as you recompile.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1